# Repeating captures in Python strange result

Tags: python, regex

I would like to repeat for natural numbers to occur and catch all of them.

```
import re
r = "the ((sixty|six)[ -]+)+items"
s = "the sixty six items"
re.findall(r, s)
# [('six ', 'six')]
```

It matches 'six' 2 times, while it can be observed that it could have never matched on "six six"; instead it had to have matched on "sixty six", but the capture returns ('six', 'six').

What is happening here and how can I return ('sixty', 'six')?

Comment: `it could have never matched on "six six"` ... yes it can, `(sixty|six)` means match `sixty` _or_ `six`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Wrong, because if it has to match them in succession, where does the "ty" get matched in the six six case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`re.search` just finds the first thing that matches the pattern, it doesn't look for further matches once it's found one. You are getting `('six ', 'six')` because you have one capture group nested inside another; the `'six '` matches the outer group, and the `'six'` (without a trailing space) matches the inner group.

You can do what you want using two un-nested capture groups inside some non-capture groups, which use the `(?:...)` syntax.

```
import re

r = "the (?:(?:(sixty)|(six))[ -]+)+items"
s = "the sixty six items"
m = re.search(r, s)
if m:
    print(m.groups())
```

**output**

```
('sixty', 'six')
```

This returns a tuple of two items because we have two capture groups in the pattern.

Here's a longer demo.

```
import re

pat = re.compile("the (?:(?:(sixty)|(six))[ -]+)+items")

data = (
    "the items",
    "the six items",
    "the six six items",
    "the sixty items",
    "the six sixty items",
    "the sixty six items",
    "the sixty-six items",
    "the six sixty sixty items",
)

for s in data:
    m = pat.search(s)
    print('{!r} -> {}'.format(s, m.groups() if m else None))
```

**output**

```
'the items' -> None
'the six items' -> (None, 'six')
'the six six items' -> (None, 'six')
'the sixty items' -> ('sixty', None)
'the six sixty items' -> ('sixty', 'six')
'the sixty six items' -> ('sixty', 'six')
'the sixty-six items' -> ('sixty', 'six')
'the six sixty sixty items' -> ('sixty', 'six')
```

Comment: How does this scale when we also include `seven` and `seventy`? Somehow I get a lot of `None` matches in between. Using `r = "the (?:(?:(sixty)|(six)|(seven)|(seventeen))[ -]+)+items"`

Comment: @PascalvKooten: That pattern has 4 capture groups, so when you search with it `.groups` will return tuples of 4 elements, one for each of the capture groups in your pattern.

Comment: So I guess I will group the "-teens", "-ties" and those without suffix, and then have 3 possible groups there.... also thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `(group)+` then only last matched text will be captured in the group.

You should use `findall` with slightly different regex.

```
s = 'the sixty six items'

>>> if re.match(r'the (?:(?:sixty|six)[ -]+)+items', s):
...     re.findall(r"\b(sixty|six)[ -]+(?=.*\bitems\b)", s)
...
['sixty', 'six']
```

---

Your question has this code:

```
>>> r = "the ((sixty|six)[ -]+)+items"
>>> s = "the sixty six items"
>>> re.findall(r, s)
```

Which is returning `[('six ', 'six')]` because of quantifier used after your group i.e. `((sixty|six)[ -]+)+`

`findall` returns 2 values that are

1. `captured group #1` is  `"six "` (note a space here due to `[ -]+` in your first group)
2. `captured group #2` is `"six"` (inner group i.e. `(sixty|six)`)

Comment: Hmmm, well the actual example is where this is just a part of it; `findall` also returns `("four", "four")`

Comment: But that group #0 could not have been 'six', so it seems something strange is going on?

Comment: The problem is that I would like to do "re.findall" at a higher level. E.g. I would like to match multiple times the `s`, problem is then that: `re.findall(r"(sixty|six)[ -]+(?=.*\bitems)", s + s + s)`, will return it as a flat list, where we lose this higher level findall match grouping.

Comment: I'm considering that solution, thanks a lot for your help! It's just that I find this behavior of "the actual question" not to be explainable!

Comment: I have tried to explain the problem with actual question in my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\b` assertion: Hope this helps.

```
>>> s = "the sixty six items"
>>> print(re.findall(r'(?is)(\bsixty\b|\bsix\b)',s))
['sixty', 'six']
```

`\b` assertion will avoid false hit, for example : If you add sixteen and do not wish to match

Without `\b`

```
>>> s = "the sixty sixteen six items"
>>> print(re.findall(r'(?is)(sixty|six)',s))
['sixty', 'six', 'six']
```

With `\b` (advantage)

```
>>> s = "the sixty sixteen six items"
>>> print(re.findall(r'(?is)(\bsixty\b|\bsix\b)',s))
['sixty', 'six']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try regex

```
re.findall('(six\w*)', s)
```

Comment: Could possibly get false hits, e.g. I do not want to hit "sixteenth"